# How to read table of MS Word in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a table with 8 columns in MS Word. 7 columns are text based and one contains image. I want to read all values row by row and show in controls on form.  I have tried following code its giving me an error. Also this code is for text I think

```
           w = new Word.Application();
        var document = w.Documents.Open(tbWordFile.Text.Trim());
for (int iCounter = 1; iCounter <= document.Tables.Count; iCounter++)
        {
            foreach (Row in document.Tables[iCounter].Rows)
            {
                foreach (Cell aCell in aRow.Cells)
                {
                    currLine = aCell.Range.Text;
                    //Process Line
                }
            }
        }
```

There is An error occured on "Row" variable is that "Row is inaccessible due to
its protection level

Comment: what error this code gives you?

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (Row in document.Tables[iCounter].Rows)
```

you are iterating rows and your per item is what? You declare `Row` with no variable name. This should be something like:

```
  foreach (Row aRow in document.Tables[iCounter].Rows)
```